# Sorting table into new table

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to figure this one out for ages so decided to turn here.

I currently have a database that has a ton of rows but as an example it looks like the below:

```
 ___________________________________
|  column1  |  column2  |  column3  |
|-----------------------------------|
| 123       |     UK    | answeruk1 |
| 321       |     UK    | answeruk3 |
| 111       |     EN    | answeren2 |
| 321       |     EN    | answeren3 |
| 111       |     FR    | answerfr2 |
| 123       |     FR    | answerfr1 |
| 111       |     UK    | answeruk2 |
| 321       |     FR    | answerfr3 |
| 123       |     EN    | answeren1 |
```

I am trying to get this to be inserted into a new table so the structure is like the below:

```
 _______________________________________________
|  column1  |  column2  |  column3  |  column4  |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| 123       | answerfr1 | answeruk1 | answeren1 |
| 321       | answerfr3 | answeruk3 | answeren3 |
| 111       | answerfr2 | answeruk2 | answeren2 |
```

This is so they are all organised by column1 but are in columns by there respective country code found in column2

I have tried using INSERT INTO but i can't seem to get my head around how i can sort 3 columns at the same time with 1 query. There are also a ton(around 15,000-20,000) of id's (the number found in column1).

I have also tried using PHP which i think may be the only way of doing this maybe within a while statement to loop through all the id's?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think that your new structure make any sense.

Comment: Problem is that you add another language and you have to rebuild the table when using your new structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a group by query and do the database pivot in one command:

```
mysql> select * from tt;
+------+------+------+
| id   | att  | val  |
+------+------+------+
|    1 | a    | b1   |
|    1 | b    | b2   |
|    1 | c    | b3   |
|    2 | a    | b4   |
|    2 | b    | b5   |
+------+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> create table tt2  select id, group_concat(case when att="a" then val end) a, group_concat(case when att="b" then val end) b, group_concat(case when att="c" then val end) c from tt group by id;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.10 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from tt2;
+------+------+------+------+
| id   | a    | b    | c    |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 | b1   | b2   | b3   |
|    2 | b4   | b5   | NULL |
+------+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This does it thanks a ton! How would i make it insert into a current table rather than create new? Thanks

Comment: It's actually the same, just replace create table with insert into: 

insert into tt2 select ....

Comment: thanks! Sorry to be a pain I have one more question, would I be able to create a button that executes this query? Thanks a ton!

Comment: Button ? This is a very different question. You probably mean HTML page button ? Read on at https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp
or other sources

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I wanted to have a html button that would execute that query but i can't seem to get it to work, and wasn't sure if it was possible.

Comment: What's your actual problem ? Building an HTML page with a button, setting up a web server, writing a PHP page called by the button, using SQL in the PHP page ?